# Find density function

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ random variables independent and uniformly distributed in $[-1,1]$. Let $R= \sqrt{X^2+Y^2+Z^2}$. Find the density function of $X^2/R^2$, assuming $R^2 \leq 1$.

My attempt: I was trying to find a density function for $X/R$ first but I was unable to find the correct transformation for that purpouse.

Comment: So we start with a cube, we restrict ourself to a sphere then compute the density of $\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2+Z^2}$ through a symmetry trick. It ultimately boils down to the broken stick problem.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific about your hint. I had trouble following it.

Comment: The density function is given by $2(1-z)$ and it is supported on $[0,1]$. Try to solve the following problem: we consider a uniform measure over the set $\{X,Y,Z\geq 0,X+Y+Z=1\}$. What is the density function of $X$? Then try to understand why the last problem and yours are indeed the same problem.